# Getting Handle of DirectX Output inside a WPF Window

Tags: wpf, windows, directx

I am hoping this makes sense.

I am developing an application which will be a plugin inside of an existing application. The application has DirectX output that is placed in a WPF container/window.

I would like to get a "handle" on that DirectX output such that I can change basic properties of that Output such as switching to a stereoscopic 3d display, switching said output to full screen, etc.

I am not trying to manipulate the objects/information/etc. of that output, just how it is presented.

Any direction I can head in?

Thank you.

Comment: If you can not touch the code of the application which has the DirectX output, the only way I think is hooking.

Comment: Thanks; Others have sent me links to DirectX/Direct3D hooking and it certainly is a project. It seems to be the way to go though.